# Ways to integrate javascript modules into one file for deployment?

Tags: javascript, module, integration, loading, code-organization

On development, I am using JS modules for a better organization of my code. For example, I have `module1.js`, `module2.js` and both modules are included in the `main.js` with [LABjs](http://labjs.com/documentation.php)

```
$LAB
.script("module1.js").wait()
.script("module2.js").wait();
```

However, I also use Google Closure Compiler for code optimization and it requires a integrated javascript file according to the [documentation](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3.html#movecalls).

> The simplest solution to this problem is to compile your functions together with the portion of your program that calls those functions.

So I want to **integrate all the modules into one js file** which could then compiled with Google Closure Compiler. LabJS runs on the client side and won't get things done on the server-side. So is there any tools to perform this job?  Or is there other library supports server-side module integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) has offered an optimization tool which could

> Combines related scripts together into build layers and minifies them via UglifyJS (the default) or Closure Compiler (an option when using Java).

In the Documentation, for a page with the following `main.js` which imports `one.js`, `two.js` and `three.js`:

`require(["one", "two", "three"], function (one, two, three) {
});`

This optimization tool could compress them into one integrated file is

`node ../../r.js -o name=main out=main-built.js baseUrl=.`

Answer (score 0):

Well in theory you can just concatenate the files together with a simple utility like [cat](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cat). *.js files are just segments of Javascript, and (assuming none of them have syntax errors) they can be spliced together just like *.txt files. You would do this on each deploy, so the input files can remain separated and closurebuilder is run against the generated artifact. e.g.

```
compile-js:
  // Concatenate the input files
  cat js/main.js js/module1.js js/module2.js > generated/intermediate.js
  // Compile the optimised output
  closurebuilder.py \
    --root=closure-library/ \
    --root=generated/ \
    --namespace="myproject.start"
```

Also, have you considered the second solution? For that, you need to "export" the symbols that are being marked as dead code by Closure, this is as simple as creating a global variable with the same name:

```
window['LAB'] = $LAB;
```

The best approach will depend on how many functions you need to include, and whether you require the Javascript to remain separated after compilation (some complex libraries do not play nice when integrated into third-party code).

Comment: I thought about this too. But as there are many pages using different modules and certainly the functions will be updated, changed and deleted along the development. Thus export the function in closure is painful for maintenance. The way to concatenate mannually doesn't smell DRY for me.

Comment: You certainly wouldn't concatenate manually. As part of the deploy script: "cat js/main.js js/module1.js js/module2.js > compiled.js", then you simply run your closure builder against the generated "compiled.js" file.

Comment: the two steps (concatenate -> compile) procedure is a choice. I also found RequireJS has come with a optimized tool which performs these two steps in one command. Better solution if you have different modules to be loaded on different page. Worth checking out.